# Excel increasing cell's number of row inside formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

i'm trying to make a formula in column K like this:

```
in K1 I want: C1*C1001
in K2 I want: C1001*C2001
in K3 I want: C2001*C3001  etc
```

I couldn't find a way to put formula in  cell's row number
Can anyone help me make this possible?

Answer (score 3):

### INDEX to Offset Rows

In cell `K1` use the following:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,(ROW()-1)*1000+1)*INDEX($C:$C,ROW()*1000+1)
```

and copy down.

In Microsoft 365, if you know an approximate number of these multiplications, you could use the SEQUENCE function, e.g.:

```
=INDEX($C:$C,SEQUENCE(20,,1,1000))*INDEX($C:$C,SEQUENCE(20,,1001,1000))
```

which will, in this particular case, spill 20 results in `K1:K20`. It will also let you put it where ever you want while the first solution is tied to a cell in the first row.